# Get file from database with Php sessions

Tags: php, sql

How can i upload images as part of registration data to database with sql and get it with php sessions everytime the user logs in
I already have this for saving username,email and password..but i want to add image to serve as profile picture during the registration and should be able to call it everytime a user logs in

```
    <?php
    session_start();

    $username = "";
    $email    = "";
    $errors = array(); 

    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'registration');

    if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {
      $fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $POST['fname']);
      $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
      $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
      $password_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_1']);
      $password_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_2']);

      if (empty($fname)) { array_push($errors, "Please Enter your full name");}
      if (empty($username)) { array_push($errors, "Username is required"); }
      if (empty($email)) { array_push($errors, "Email is required"); }
      if (empty($password_1)) { array_push($errors, "Password is required"); }
      if ($password_1 != $password_2) {
        array_push($errors, "The two passwords do not match");
      }

      $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' OR email='$email' LIMIT 1";
      $result = mysqli_query($db, $user_check_query);
      $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

      if ($user) { 
        if ($user['username'] === $username) {
          array_push($errors, "Username already exists");
        }

        if ($user['email'] === $email) {
          array_push($errors, "email already exists");
        }
      }


      if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $password = md5($password_1);

        $query = "INSERT INTO users (fname, username, email, password) 
                  VALUES( '$fname', '$username', '$email', '$password')";
        mysqli_query($db, $query);
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
        header('location: /me/home.php');
      }
    }

    ________________________LOGIN____________________________

    if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
      $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
      $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

      if (empty($username)) {
        array_push($errors, "Username is required");
      }
      if (empty($password)) {
        array_push($errors, "Password is required");
      }

      if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $password = md5($password);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
        $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
          $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
          $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
          header('location: /me/home.php');
        }else {
            array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
        }
      }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Welcome to the platform. This is not exactly how asking a question works. Add your code, show what you have tried already. If you haven't tried anything yet, try searching first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i will assume you have already finished the login authentication.

you will have to include an input of type file in your registration page.

here is the php code you will need to insert the photo:

```
  extract($_POST);

  if(isset($upload)) // Upload variable here is the button user clicks when he registers
    {


        $query = "insert into users (picture)values (?)";
            $result = $db->prepare($query);


            $target_path = "profilePictures/" . $un . "_";
            $target_path = $target_path.basename($_FILES['profilePic']['name']); 

            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['profilePic']['tmp_name'], $target_path))
            {
                $newPic = "profilePictures/" . $un . "_" . basename($_FILES['profilePic']['name']);
                $result->bindParam(1, $newPic);

            }

            $result->execute();
            $db=NULL;
            if ($result)
            {
                $success = true;


            success("Information inserted Successfully "); //success here is a function i created you can just echo this message instead.
            }
            else
            {
                error("Failed");
            }
        }
    }
```

now when a user logs in from the login page you will have to do some coding where you need it to be:

```
 session_start();

 $username=$_SESSION['activeUser']; // 
  query="select * from users where username='$username'";
  $result = $db->prepare($query);
$result->execute();
$row=$result->fetch();
$userpic=$row['picture'];
 $_SESSION['picture'] = $userpic; // here the image will be saved in a session and you 
 can save it in a variable elsewhere and use it.
```

Comment: You can take the code for uploading an image i put above and include it in your registration page. Just follow my code and make proper adjustments @Xenonwellz